# Android WebView how download files

Tags: android, webview

I am developing an Android App based on a WebView.

The App has some links, for example

```
<a href='/path/file.jpg'>
```

as well as

```
<a href='/path/file.jpg' download='myfile.jpg'>
```

Files may have different extensions (example png, pdf, doc, ...)

What i would like to do is: when a user click the first link, the file is shown in the webview, while when the user click the second link, the file has to be downloaded because of the download attribute.

This works fine in a standard computer with chrome browser, but not in the Android App.

In Android App: click on the first link results in the file shown in webview but click on the second link produces no results (nothing happen on click).

In the Android App Manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

What else do I need ?

Comment: Well what happens in the Android app instead?

Comment: For the first link that image should be shown in the webview itself and not in an external browser app.

Comment: yes, the first image is shown in the webview (i edited the question). when i click the second link, nothing happen

Comment: What did you do to let the first link open in the webview itself?

Comment: nothing. It seems to be an automatic behaviour of webview in android

Comment: No. You have implemented a on link click listener and the listener decides if the url goes to the webview or if you do noting to an external browser. But you are not showing any code..

Comment: Use a download manager for the webview